# AddIndexToColumn on postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

So I have a table whit a lot of data, and I just added a index on a column.

My question is do I need to run a command or something to run the indexing, or is it automatic? Because I seems that there is no difference, when it should be.

Comment: Did you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: You should be running `rake db:migrate` after adding index to your migration file.

Comment: Yes I did migrate my changes.

Comment: What makes you think that there should be any difference? There is no such simple implication like `add index => improved performance` in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Well because in order to filter the results that I want, I use the column which was indexed.

Comment: If you think an index that should be being used is not, please show `explain analyze` output for the query in question. To force index use (for testing purposes only) you might want `set enable_seqscan = off;` and possibly other join/scan types, depending on the query. see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`REINDEX TABLE X`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reindex.html), but index should be created when you add it.

PostgreSQL is quite smart and sometimes it won't use index, because there is faster way to produce required results.

When you are facing slow performance it would be good to see what queries are actually being used. Then you can use [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) to understand why index is not being used.

Comment: Also, sometimes it's not choosing the fastest plan because the planner parameters like `random_page_cost` are giving it bad information about relative performance. Garbage in, garbage out.